# Can't access Post request data from request.data in Django

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm having a lot difficulty accessing the post request data sent from my Angular server. Somehow Response(data) still returns the body of my post request accurately, however I can't access the content inside to create instance of my model.
Below is my code

Angular end:

```
let header = new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': ' JWT ' + this.authToken,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});

let body = {
  "var1": var1,
  "var2": var2,
};

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.post(this.server, body, {headers: header, withCredentials: true}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Django

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def order_processing(request):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    data = request.data
    item = Item.create(data["var1"])
    item.save()
    return Response(data)
```

and I always end up getting the error:

```
TypeError at /post/↵create() missing 1 required positional argument:
```

which I think is due to data["var1"] being unavailable. Item is my custom model.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # Fields
    var1 = models.TextField(editable=False)

    # Methods
    def __str__(self):
        return self.var1

    def create(self, var1):
        order = self.create(var1=var1)
        return order
```

On my localhost, I tried to use httpie to request and both Querydict and request.data are empty. But then Response(data) on my deployed server is still able to return the correct body so I don't know what exactly is the problem with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is Item ? a Serializer ? a Model ?

Comment: It's my custom model.

Comment: create is not class method ( probably - unless you did it yourself). Try to do this : Item.objects.create(<data>)

Comment: create is a method in my model.

Comment: So, in that case, provide the implementation.

Comment: @Sylph  there's already a `create` method in `ModelManager`, putting a `create` method on the instance will only confuse everyone. Better to stick to the framework's conventions.

Comment: Also: "which I think is due to data["var1"] being unavailable" => nope, this would raise a `KeyError`

Comment: Also a method whose implementation consists in calling itself is not going to work...

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment - your create method is not classmethod. So you can't call it like you do. Because it can be called only on a instance.

But, the create is not going to work like  you'd like.

Do this instead:

1. remove the create method from your model
2. in your view do this :
    `item = Item.objects.create(var1=data['var1'])`

This will create the item.

Also another thing:
your `permission_classes` don't do anything.

Instead, import the decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
```

And change it to:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def order_processing(request):
   ....
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct, but the stuff about permission_classes is totally wrong; you should delete it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman hm.areyou sure? i dont see how the request can be authenticated after it enters the function ( the permission classes variable in the original impl. is not going to be used ).

Comment: You're right, now that you've removed the syntax error the code is fine.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your implementation and it works perfectly!